# What property to transition to animate the space created when adding an element to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm looking to insert an element in to the DOM inline with some text. In some cases, the text is justified, center aligned, etc. However, I would like whatever text that will be pushed around by this new element to tween into it's new position, rather than just jump to it. Example:

[image]
[image]

The bars represent the parent width. El 1-5 here are justified. When I add El 6 to the DOM (potentially by having it already there, but changing it's `display` from `none` to `inline-block`), I would like El 1-5 to slide into their new position, rater than jump to it. Setting `transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;` does not seem to do it. How is this accomplished?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o00v389y/) to make this easier to mess around with

Comment: have you tried applying the transition to the width of the elements? since the width is what is getting adjusted here. Not sure what it's going to look like with a bunch of them changing at the same time though.

Comment: @Brodie Just gave it a shot, didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: can you provide some sample structure/css so we can see what you are working with. are the child elements just set as inline-blocks? do they have a width or anything set to them?

Comment: You've added a lot of strange styles so it's probably not going to work like you want it to, but this is how you'd do it -> **https://jsfiddle.net/o00v389y/2/**

Comment: @adeneo The problematic part with this is that when el1 is hidden, it's still part of the parent, and so el2 – el6 do not justify fully, because there is still the 0px wide el1 at the beginning

Comment: @Brodie not entirely sure what you mean. There's a fiddle in the question, if you didn't see it! :)

Comment: And again, that's because you have the strangest CSS, creating margins with pseudo elements and justify.

Comment: sorry for some reason didn't see the fiddle link. i don't think that you can animate them w/ css transitions in the current set up... even when you set the transition to all nothing happens. If you were to set this up so you're setting a property (like the left value or width or something) with each toggle, you could use transitions and it would work.  but managing position manually might not be something that you want to do/can do in this situation (not sure how many dynamic items you'll be adding, etc).

Comment: @adeneo hmm. Is there a better way to handle it? Justifying text that is only one line does not work, and every solution I saw was to add the pseudo element to create an "extra" line, thereby justifying the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for flex boxes! See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

```
#sections {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#sections div
{
    flex: 1;   
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
/* note the use of keyframes for the flex attribute in the fiddle though */
```

See this **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/EM4xL/

Comment: AWESOME answer, I had no idea these even existed! Thanks!

Comment: I guess one proviso is just to note browser compatibility with them. But yes, awesome!

Comment: It works on android opera browser nicely. And maybe on others as well